TypeError: Failed to fetch, 400 error in network console, but not in exception
I am attempting to call the Google Drive REST API to upload a file from a browser context using the fetch api, but am not able to progress past a weird error.
TypeError: Failed to fetch

Looking at other posts on the topic, some point to a CORS failure, but it's pretty difficult to determine exactly what the error is from this message. The strange thing is, looking at the Network tab of the Chrome devtools tells a different story:

Now I'll be the first to admit that there's a (high?) chance I'm sending a malformed request, but it's also pretty difficult to determine what about the request is malformed without any error message.
What I'm doubly confused by, is why the fetch call is rejecting (throws error with await), rather than resolving with a 400 response.
The code to make the call is about as basic as it gets:
await fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart`, options);

The options object is pretty boiler-plate, and just sets things like an Authorization header, Content-Type, Content-Length, as well as the body which (in this case) is multipart/related
So I neither get a graceful resolve response with a message, nor do I get useful reject outcome, rather just TypeError: Failed to fetch
If I were to rely on the rejection alone, I would have no idea this was actually a 400. It was only the Network tools that revealed this.
Anyone have a clue why this 400 error would be "swallowed", and what I need to do to capture it?
Additional Edits
Further detail in response to comments. The code around the fetch looks like this:
async send() {
  this._build();
  return await fetch(this._parameterizedUrl, this._options);
}

This is contained in an object which just encapsulates the process of creating a request (called a Request). So the this pointer refers to the encapsulating object. this._parameterizedUrl is just the value of the URL string already posted, and this._options is the options object already mentioned. The call to build() just assembles the values of the Request object, mostly into the options argument (but also supports URL parameters, not used in this case)
The code calling this looks like:
const request = Request.post(uploadUrl);
request.setContentType(contentType);
request.setBody(body);
request.setAccessToken(accessToken);
request.addHeader('Content-Length', contentLength);
const response = await request.send();

The Request.post(uploadUrl) call is a shorthand to create my Request object (this is my own encapsulation as mentioned)
This call will throw an error, which is caught at an earlier point in the stack. The next line of the trace from the Failed to fetch error looks like this:
TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at Request.send (api.js:240:1)

Full Reproduction
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async () => {
  
  const url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart';
  const options = {};
  const authToken = '<Add Auth Token>';
  const boundary = 'boundary-' + Math.random().toString(36).substring(2);
  const contentType = `multipart/related; boundary=${boundary}`;

  // Body part meta data for the filename
  const meta = {
    name: 'test.json'
  };

  // Body part for media (the file)
  const data = {
    foo: "bar",
    bar: "baz"
  }

  const metaBlob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(meta)], {
    type: 'application/json',
  });

  const mediaBlob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(data)], {
    type: 'application/json',
  });

  const body = new FormData();
  body.append('metadata', metaBlob, "metadata");
  body.append('media', mediaBlob, name);
  let contentLength = metaBlob.size + mediaBlob.size;

  const headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${authToken}`);
  headers.append('Content-Type', contentType);
  headers.append('Content-Length', contentLength);

  options['method'] = 'POST';
  options['headers'] = headers;
  options['body'] = body;

  try {
    const response = await fetch(url, options);
    console.log(response);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
});


Click that Response tab for any details from the server about the bad request

Please [edit] your question to show some more code around that fetch() call. How exactly are you handling the response and any errors

Can you provide your current script to correctly replicate your current issue by removing your access token? And, how much size is the file you want to upload to Google Drive? By the way, your access token can be used to upload files using Drive API. Is my understanding correct?

@Phil Response tab is blank/empty, with just a message that says, "Failed to load response data: No data found for resource with given identifier." I don't really know what that means. I will edit the question with more detail on the code

@Tanaike I can work on an isolated repro (which would likely be my next step). File is tiny. Right now it's a hand-crafted JSON file just to get things working (I'm aware of the 5MB limit). Access token is likely not authorized right now. I have the oauth dance to create the right token, but right now I'm not really trying to debug why Google is rejecting the request, but why fetch is not bubbling the error

Thank you for replying. I understood the file size. About Access token is likely not authorized right now., in order to test it, how about retrieving an access token using OAuth 2.0 Playground? And, can you provide the value of this._options and body?

I'd definitely avoid naming custom classes the same as existing built-in interfaces - Request. Is this just in standard web app JS code or is it a web-worker / browser extension? I find it hard to believe that there would be nothing in the Response tab of the Network console. Do you at least receive response headers?

Added a reproducible example

OK.. Interesting.. loading my sample repro into Firefox gives more info: "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 400" So I guess I need some sort of CORS header in the request, which is weird to me

"I guess I need some sort of CORS header in the request"... no, that's not how it works

@Phil Good call on using Request as a class name. I will rename it (didn't realize there was one in the spec). And on CORS.. yeah.. that's why it seems weird. Should surely only be a response header

Google's API probably doesn't include Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers on error responses. I'd say your problem is posting a FormData body but your content-type header doesn't actually match the type or the mime boundary tokens

From your showing script, I modified it. Please confirm it.

@Phil The lack of CORS headers on error responses seems plausible, but also.. I mean.. completely unworkable in practice. That would imply that any non-200 error is going to present as a "failed to fetch", which itself is swallowing an underlying CORS failure. I mean, you might be right, but I'm a bit lost as to how anyone could handle different actual error cases

Raise a bug with Google. FYI a 401 response does contain the appropriate headers so it's not all errors where it's missing

For posterity, the reason you're not seeing any details and the reason this goes directly to your catch block is indeed a CORS error.
The API does actually support CORS, at least for preflight and successful requests...
curl -v \
  -X OPTIONS \
  -H "Origin: https://example.com" \
  -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: POST" \
  -H "Access-Control-Request-Headers: authrorization,content-type,content-length" \
  "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart"

< HTTP/2 200
< access-control-allow-headers: authrorization,content-type,content-length
< access-control-allow-methods: DELETE,GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,PATCH,POST,PUT
< access-control-allow-origin: https://example.com

The problem is one you'll see in many implementations where CORS response headers are not added for some or all unsuccessful requests. In this particular case, your incorrect content-type header handling results in a 400 Bad Request response which is missing the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header so your client-side code has no access and fetch() fails with a TypeError.
I would not be surprised if there wasn't another error present in your Console. Something like

Access to fetch at 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart' from origin 'https://example.com has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart net::ERR_FAILED 400 (Bad Request)


Awesome. Thanks. I mean, super-annoying... I'm sure I would have favored an "invalid content-type" (or equivalent) error from the API :/

In your showing script, how about the following modification?
Modification points:

In this case, the content type and content length in the request header are automatically created. So, headers.append('Content-Type', contentType); and headers.append('Content-Length', contentLength); are removed.
In order to retrieve the returned value from Drive API, I added const res = await response.json();. By this, the file metadata of the uploaded file can be seen with console.log(res);.
In your showing script, the boundary is manually given at const contentType = `multipart/related; boundary=${boundary}`;. But, the request body is automatically created by FormData(). At that time, the boundary and content type are also automatically created. But, your given content type overwrites the automatically created content type. By this, the request body cannot be correctly parsed on the server side. So, I guessed that such an error occurred.

Modified script:
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Google Drive Test</title>
  <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async () => {
      
      const url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart';
      const options = {};
      const authToken = '<Add Auth Token>';

      // Body part meta data for the filename
      const meta = {
        name: 'test.json'
      };

      // Body part for media (the file)
      const data = {
        foo: "bar",
        bar: "baz"
      }

      const metaBlob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(meta)], {
        type: 'application/json',
      });

      const mediaBlob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(data)], {
        type: 'application/json',
      });

      const body = new FormData();
      body.append('metadata', metaBlob, "metadata");
      body.append('media', mediaBlob, name);

      const headers = new Headers();
      headers.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${authToken}`);

      options['method'] = 'POST';
      options['headers'] = headers;
      options['body'] = body;

      try {
        const response = await fetch(url, options);
        const res = await response.json();
        console.log(res);
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>

When this script is run, when your access token is valid and Drive API is enabled, the following result is obtained. The file is created in the root folder.
{
  "kind":"drive#file",
  "id":"###",
  "name":"test.json",
  "mimeType":"application/json"
}


This still fails for me with the same error. I don't get to the response handling. Could this be due to running from localhost?

So.. this is not really the issue though. I am not trying to get the code to work (i.e. upload). I am trying to diagnose why the fail case didn't actually provide a meaningful error.

@Jason Polites Thank you for replying. About This still fails for me with the same error. I don't get to the response handling. Could this be due to running from localhost?, it's yes. I tested this in my browser using a HTML file on my PC.

@Jason Polites I updated my answer by including the modification points. If that was not useful, I apologize.

your modification is useful, if for no other reason than to validate that the code works, but it unfortunately doesn't help resolve the underlying (and original) question of why the 400 error did not present as a 400 error in the response. But thank you for your attention

@Jason Polites Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize that my answer was not useful for your situation. Now, I added a point of the reason for your current error.
